# Synthesising a circuit when \$Z_{21}\$ is known

Tags: passive-networks

I have a \$Z_{21}\$ parameter of a circuit which is given by $$ Z_{21}(s) = \dfrac{s}{s^3 + 2s^2 + 2s + 1}$$

I would like to synthesize as an L-C ladder network with \$ 1 \Omega\$ resistive termination. There is a relation 
$$Z_{21} = \dfrac{z_{21}}{z_{22} + 1} = \dfrac{\dfrac{s}{2s^2+1}}{\dfrac{s^3+2s}{2s^2 + 1} + 1}$$

Using this, I can synthesize the L-C network using partial fraction expansion of \$z_{22}\$.

Method 1: I pull out an \$s\$ term first.
$$z_{22} = \dfrac{s^3+2s}{2s^2 + 1} = \dfrac{s}{2} + \dfrac{\dfrac{3s}{2}}{2s^2+1} = \dfrac{s}{2} + \dfrac{1}{\dfrac{4s}{3} + \dfrac{2}{3s}}$$

Using this expression, the overall circuit can be synthesized as

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fK3ptG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Method 2: I rewrite \$ z_{22}\$ in the below fashion and pull out \$\dfrac{1}{s}\$ term first.

$$z_{22} = \dfrac{s^3+2s}{2s^2 + 1} = \dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1+2s^2}{2s+s^3}} = \dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1}{2s} + \dfrac{\dfrac{3s^2}{2}}{2s+s^3}} = \dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1}{2s} + \dfrac{1}{\dfrac{4}{3s} + \dfrac{2s}{3}}}$$

This can be synthesized as

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0Zkid.png)</sup>

I would like to know which of the above synthesis of \$Z_{21}\$ is correct?

Comment: Maybe you need to demonstrate that method 1's partial fraction reduction is correct. On a scrap of paper I got a different result. I'm not saying I'm right. No, my mistake you are right.

Comment: Maybe its a dumb though due to my feverish state but why do you assume that only one solution would exist?

Comment: @ChristianB. If you look into the example provided on Page 34 of this book (https://www.slideshare.net/krishna0024/synthesis-network), the \$Z_{21}\$, in this case, is a LPF. So, out of the two solutions obtained, One is LPF where as the other is BPF. Hence only one is correct. So, I am thinking only one may be correct and can be identified by the magnitude response. But, In my question \$Z_{21}\$ is BPF and both my methods gave BPFs' and I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

I have plotted the \$|Z_{21}|^2\$ vs \$w\$ for Circuit 1, Circuit 2 and using the given equation. [image]

The plots are matching up to a constant scaling factor. Hence, I am concluding that the synthesis is not unique for a given Transfer Function.